# Solve this equation on x (x is a real number)

Tags: systems-of-equations, roots, real-numbers, continued-fractions

How does anyone solve this equation on $x$ ($x$ is a real number)?

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}=x+\cfrac{x}{x+\cfrac{x}{x+\cfrac{x}{\cdots}}}$$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}=y;\quad y=x+\cfrac{x}{x+\cfrac{x}{x+\cfrac{x}{\cdots}}}$$

System $\sqrt{x+y}=y;\quad y=x+\dfrac{x}{y}$

both $x$ and $y$ are positive

$x+y=y^2\to x=y^2-y$

plug in the second equation

$y=y^2-y+\dfrac{y^2-y}{y}\to y=y^2-y+y-1$

$y^2-y-1=0\to y=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

and $x=\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$x=1$

Hope it helps

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much. And y is... the Golden Ratio!
The number 1 makes it possible for the equation to yield the Golden Number.

Comment: If $\sqrt{x + y} = y$ and $x + \frac{x}{y} = y$, then surely you could make this shorter by saying $x + y = y^2$ and $xy + x = y^2$. You can then equate these two equations getting: $x + y = xy + x \Rightarrow xy = y \Rightarrow x = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $L(x)$ and $R(x)$ are the left-hand side and the right-hand side respectively, then 
$$L(x)=\sqrt{x+L(x)}=x+\frac{x}{R(x)}=R(x).$$
Hence $L(x)> 0$, $R(x)>0$, 
$$L^2(x)=L(x)+x\quad\mbox{and}\quad R^2(x)=xR(x)+x.$$
Finally, from $L(x)=R(x)$, we obtain
$$L(x)+x=xL(x)+x\implies (1-x)L(x)=0\implies x=1.$$

P.S. Note that
$$L(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}\quad\mbox{and}\quad R(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had already got to that. But how do you solve it from there?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how it goes from the first equation to the second one. My question stands for R(x). I got a different quadratic equation than yours.

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Gooble I edited my answer with the full solution. Any further doubts?